# vb.net: Does datagridview have a similar function as textbox.paste?

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, paste

I need to be able to add some text in the DataGridView cell where my cursor is. On a TextBox I can do this with `TextBox.Paste("test")`. Can i convert the cell to a TextBox or is there another method?

example:
when i have a cell with the text: "this is(cursor is here) an example" and i click a button the tekst should be: "this istest an example"

Comment: I am not sure if I'm getting your question, but you can paste into a cell in the same way you would paste to a text box. Just make sure you are inside cell edit mode (usually double click).

Comment: Ah, this example changes the question entirely. The problem is getting the cursor position within the string inside the cell when in cell edit mode. How are you going to insert text when your mouse is inside the cell? You can't exactly click a button...

Comment: It works fine with a textbox using "TextBox.Paste("test")". I thought a cell in editmode is a textbox  so it would work with a cell too

Comment: The cell is not a textbox though. The trick is converting the cell to a textbox, which can only be one at a certain time. See my new answer.

Answer (score 0):

Since the edit, your question is a lot more clear. This solution inserts text into the *latest* cursor position within the DataGridViewCell. I am doing that with a button click. You will need to have a DataGridView called DataGridView1 and a TextBox called InsertTextBox on your form

```
Private lastTextBox As TextBox
Private lastCursorPosition As Integer
Private lastCell As DataGridViewCell

Private Sub InsertTextButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles InsertTextButton.Click
    If lastCell IsNot Nothing Then lastCell.Value = CType(lastCell.Value, String).Insert(lastCursorPosition, "test")
End Sub

Private Sub DataGridView1_EditingControlShowing(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.EditingControlShowing
    lastTextBox = CType(e.Control, TextBox)
End Sub

Private Sub DataGridView1_CellEndEdit(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellEndEdit
    lastCell = DataGridView1(e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex)
    lastCursorPosition = lastTextBox.SelectionStart
End Sub
```